# AFNetworking 2.0 header Content-Type not being sent on POST call

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to convert some NSURLConnection code to AFNetworking 2.0 and I'm having issues with the POST calls. The GET calls work but not the POST.

Here's my code:

```
+(void)login:(User*)myUser
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:myUser.username password:myUser.password];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [manager POST:URL_LOGIN
       parameters:nil
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              NSLog(@"success! Response = %@", responseObject);
          } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"failure. Error = %@", error);
          }];
}
```

And here's the error I get back from the server:

```
Error Domain=com.<server>.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo=0x7fe043c43670 {com.<server>.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fe043d52850> { URL: http://<server>/login.htm;jsessionid=98399EA8F090BF310D1CF5FD3C992A21?login_error=1 } { status code: 200, headers {
"Content-Language" = en;
"Content-Length" = 2801;
"Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1";
Date = "Tue, 28 Apr 2015 15:30:21 GMT";
Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
```

I have also tried to place the Content-Type explicitly as a param but it is not working either.

I have found a lot of suggestions online that say to either modify the server (which I can't) or to just set the `manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];` which is obviously not working either.

Any suggestions on this would be highly appreciated. Also, as mentioned earlier, this communication with this Content-Type works on NSURLConnection with NSMutableURLRequest.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is sending you text/html whether you like it or not.

So you have to make this an acceptable content type in the request serializer.

You can either add it, like this:

```
  manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
```

or use a more general HTTP serializer, not a JSON serializer, like this:

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work with the "manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];" serializer and removing the call to request a specific content type.